# How to generate complete map of India in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap

I have the following dataset, now when i am plotting using ESRI India data set its showing Image1 as output and when i am using diva-gis India Data set its Showing Image 2 as dataset.  I am using ggplot2, tmap.

```
 structure(list(NAME_1 = structure(c(12L, 34L, 2L, 17L, 21L, 10L, 
31L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 
18L, 19L, 23L, 22L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 
33L, 35L, 36L), .Label = c("Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "Andhra Pradesh", 
"Arunachal Pradesh", "Assam", "Bihar", "Chandigarh", "Chhattisgarh", 
"Dadra and Nagar Haveli", "Daman and Diu", "Delhi", "Goa", "Gujarat", 
"Haryana", "Himachal Pradesh", "Jammu and Kashmir", "Jharkhand", 
"Karnataka", "Kerala", "Lakshadweep", "Madhya Pradesh", "Maharashtra", 
"Manipur", "Meghalaya", "Mizoram", "Nagaland", "Odisha", "Puducherry", 
"Punjab", "Rajasthan", "Sikkim", "Tamil Nadu", "Telangana", "Tripura", 
"Uttar Pradesh", "Uttarakhand", "West Bengal"), class = "factor"), 
    Score = c(100L, 92L, 42L, 37L, 26L, 19L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

The code i used

```
library(dplyr)
library(tmap)    
library(ggplot2)
b<-read.csv("2004.csv")
cmap<-st_read("IND_adm/IND_adm1.shp")

b_cmap<-inner_join(cmap, b)
ggplot(b_cmap)+ geom_sf(aes(fill=Score))
```

[image: Image Output]

Now i want to display result as per the desired output. How to get the desired output ?

The output should be the complete map of India.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the data using `dput` as well as the code which you have tried.

Comment: I have used shape file of india  from the source http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata and https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cf9b387de48248a687aafdd4cdff1127

Comment: To clarify, is this about changing the color scheme, about removing the grey background, about the missing regions?